# Как отследить использование камеры в node.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, npm

Найти какой-либо процесс я смог с помощью пакета `ps-node`. Но вот беда, я не вижу там используется ли камера. Помогите найти решение. Советы, типа, лучше сделать это на c# с примерами буду рад рассмотреть, но приоритет всё же на node.js

Comment: Нашёл пакет для macos. Беда в том, что использоваться будет именно на винде https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-camera-on

Comment: Самый идеальный вариант -- поставить включение камеры на событие. Камера включилась -- выполняем код